# Correcting dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in which some elements of the second column are misplaced . for example :

```
"15365","JAS ONLINE SERVICES PRIVATE LIMITED"
"15366","KRESS ITALIAN FOOD SPECIALTIES PRIVATE LIMITED"
"15367","SHATAYU CRITICARE HOSPITAL AND RESEARCH CENTER PRI
VATE LIMITED"
"15368","WHITE HEARTS FOODIES PRIVATE LIMITED"
"15369","MAAHI LOGISTICS PRIVATE LIMITED"
...
...

"15376","G S LIFE SKILLS EDUCATION WORLDWIDE PRIVATE LIMITE
D"
"15377","RED LINE LOGISTICS PRIVATE LIMITED"
```

and so on . Here row 15367 and 15376 need editing . Is there some way to do this without doing it manually ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `quote` parameter of `read.table`. Suppose you have the string in the variable `ds` and want to store the resulting `data.frame` in `my.df`:

```
my.df <- read.table(text=ds, sep=",", quote="\"")
```

If you want to remove the line breaks from the resulting column you can use the following code, just replace `replacement` with the text you want to replace the linebreaks with and `V2` with the column name of your `data.frame`.

```
my.df$V2 <- gsub("\\n", replacement, my.df$V2)
```